# Splitview Width detection not proper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i'm using splitview with jquery mobile + PhoneGap

When i load the index.html, the splitiview is working fine.

But when i navigate to sample.html, the width detection is not proper the side bar is collapsed to menu.

Is there any way to overcome this ?

Note the sample.html is external file

Comment: Initially when a page is loaded, sidebar is displayed.But when i navigate to another html page.Sidebar is collapsed to menu

Comment: u wont get any answer if u provide no details...